# How can I use the result of Vertex Weight Mix Modifier as Vertex Group input of Particle System?

Tags: particles, vertex-weights

I have a Vertex Weight Mix Modifier and a particle System. I want to control the density of the particles with the result of the Vertex Weight Mix. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible:

[image: default cube example]

**A few important notes:**

- in the *Particle System > Emission > Source* section the checkbox `[X] Use Modifier Stack` must be checked
- the *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier must be above the *Particle Settings* modifier
- the group for the mixed result must be defined as *Particle Settings > Vertex Groups > Density* and as *Vertex Group A* in the *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier settings
- you need to change the default values of the *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier to proper values, especially the *Vertex Set* and *Mix Mode*
- you can see the modified weights (*Vertex Group A*) in *Weight Paint* mode, and with help of the *Vertex Group Weights* overlay in *Edit* mode (make sure the modifier is enabled for *Edit* mode; check the icons right next to its name).

[image: screenshot 2 with settings]

The faces of the cube in this example have been inset (<kbd>I</kbd>) and each of the inner faces has been assigned to a vertex group (*Modified Top*, *Bottom*, *Left*, etc). The modifier modifies the group that is specified as *Vertex Group A*  (=*Modified Top*) depending on the other settings:

- in the 1st screenshot the modifier adds the verts of the bottom group to the top group
- in the 2nd screenshot it replaces the top group with the left one

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and that is pretty much exactly how I thought it would work. I want to animate a transition between two groups. And what threw me off was, while I could see the transition while in weight paint mode, it doesn't seem to affect the particle system. At least not in the viewport. The rendered animation on the other hand looks as expected.